# How to force sending a transaction calling method on a contract even if it reverts?

Tags: web3.py, sendtransaction, sendrawtransaction

I'm quite struggling with this from all day. I need to send a transaction on blockchain even if it says it will revert, but I can't understand how to do it since there's some kind of protection behind the buildTransaction method.
I'm using web3.py and this is what I'm doing:

```
transaction = contract_instance.functions.contract_method(
    param1,
    param2
).buildTransaction({
    'from': sender_address,
    'value': value,
    'gasPrice': gas_price,
    'nonce': nonce
})
```

Then I just sign the transaction with "sign_transaction" and send it with "send_raw_transaction".

The problem is that it reverts in console when it tries to build the transaction because he doesn't like the params I'm passing through.
Well, I just want to pass them anyway and if it fails, that's ok but I want to see the transaction on blockchain (of course paying the fees I have to).

How to do that?

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force push a failing transaction using Web3.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100054/how-to-force-push-a-failing-transaction-using-web3-js)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I already saw that thread but he uses web3.js and also he just need to send a normal transaction. What I need to do is send a transaction calling a specific method on a contract.
If I try to use the corresponding method on py, "send_transaction", I can't call the method on contract. And I also need to sign the transaction before sending it since I don't have a personal node.

Comment: The contract call, with its payload, is the data field of the transaction (this is valid for every contract interaction, sending eth is sending a transaction with an empty data field). Please not the use of "signer" as well, if properly instantiate, it will sign and send the transaction.

Comment: The duplicate shows you how to go "a level lower", by creating your transaction payload, including the function call and parameters;)

Comment: Hi Dr, thanks for reply. I just didn't understand what do you mean with "duplicate"?
Also, I tought "data" could be a way to go, but I don't know how to "encode" the function call with its parameters in that field. Could you maybe enlight me with that?
Maybe with an example, I would really appreciate that.
Thank you

Comment: Yeaaaaah I did it! It was sooo simple. Just needed to add data field to the transaction using encodeABI as function to get it encoded.
Thanks a lot!!